Is it possible to update a dependency of the updated dependencies?
When I run npm install in an Angular project I get these warnings:
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported   
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported

After running npm ls rimraf I get this information:
angularapp@3.0.0 C:\myfolder\angularapp
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.2.12
│ ├─┬ karma@6.4.4
│ │ └── rimraf@3.0.2
│ ├─┬ protractor@7.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ selenium-webdriver@3.6.0
│ │ │ └── rimraf@2.7.1 deduped
│ │ └─┬ webdriver-manager@12.1.9
│ │   ├─┬ del@2.2.2
│ │   │ └── rimraf@2.7.1 deduped
│ │   └── rimraf@2.7.1 deduped
│ └─┬ webpack-dev-server@5.0.4
│   └── rimraf@5.0.10
└─┬ karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@3.0.3
  └─┬ istanbul-lib-source-maps@3.0.6
    └── rimraf@2.7.1

After running npm outdated I see that all my dependencies have "wanted" versions for Angular 18 which I use now so there is nothing to update.
Is it possible to remove this warning or update rimraf somehow?

It's possible to override a transitive dependency, but there's no guarantee that e.g. del v2 will work with rimraf v4 when it was written and tested with rimraf v2.

No you can't, best you can do is raise a github issue on the project that has the issue del/selenium-webdriver/webdriver-manager/istanbul-lib-source-maps.
I needs to be fixed on the source project, which end users do not have control over.
